# Missing AVFoundation Framework in Xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on an App that uses a third-party framework called AudioKit which itself uses AVFoundation.

I can build the app fine to the simulators without a problem.  However, when I switch to my connected Iphone it throws a compiler error saying AVFoundation cannot be found.

[image: screenshot of xcode]

If I go to look for AVFoundation in the buildphases it is strangely absent.   What can I do to import AVFoundation?  If more information about my setup is needed let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Go to you target settings, then General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries and press `+`, you can search `AVFoundation.framework` and add it

Comment: I stated that AVFoundation is missing.